# Julia not available in Raspbian?

Tags: pi-2, software-installation, apt, packages, julia

I am trying to install [Julia](http://julialang.org/):

```
$ sudo apt-get install julia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package julia is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  julia-common

E: Package 'julia' has no installation candidate
```

I then tried to install *julia-common*, but this seems not to contain the actual language: **"This package contains the Julia standard library and test suite."**

What does this mean? Are my sources broken or is Julia just not available in the Raspbian stretch repo (but why is there a julia-common package then)?

The only line in my */etc/apt/sources.list* is:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, but you can install it fairly easy: https://juliaberry.github.io/ :)
This project gives you an precompiled binary to get started with.

`wget https://julialang.s3.amazonaws.com/bin/linux/arm/0.5/julia-0.5-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz
mkdir julia
tar -xzf julia-0.5-latest-linux-arm.tar.gz -C julia --strip-components 1 --exclude libstdc++.so.6`

does copy the needed files and you can start julia then with
`julia/bin/julia`

:)

Answer (score 4):

Julia is now available in the Raspbian repository and can be installed with **apt**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install julia
```

You can verify the install with:

```
julia -v
```

Which should return something like:

```
julia version 0.5.1
```

Note: Like many packages installed via apt is an older version.

Comment: Still does not work for me. Getting "unmet dependencies" error: https://pastebin.com/qCv9SMdd

Comment: @jitter are you running wheezy or Jessie?

Comment: I have stretch (see my original post).